# Can't obtain a continuous function when integrating

Tags: integration, absolute-value

I wish to find a continuous function that solves this integral:

$\int{\lvert\sin{2x}\rvert\sin{2x} \,\,dx}$

or equal written as

$\int{\sqrt{\sin^2{2x}} \, \sin{2x} \,\,dx}$

I have used multiple solvers and even when I make it a definite integral, i.e. $x_1$ to $x_2$, the functions returned are not continuous.  I really only need a function that is continuous for a period, i.e. 0 to $\pi$.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Of course you actually need a function that is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

In $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}], \sin (2x)\geq 0$

$$\int \sin^2 (2x)dx=\int \frac{1-\cos (4x)}{2} $$

$$=\frac {x}{2}-\frac{\sin(4x)}{8}+C_1.$$

In $[\frac {\pi}{2},\pi],\sin (2x)\leq 0$,

you add a minus,

to find

$$-\frac {x}{2}+\frac{\sin (4x)}{8}+C_2$$

to be continuous at $[0,\pi]$, you need

$C_2=C_1+\frac {\pi }{2}$.

Comment: This is still two functions, I need one function that is continuous during the whole period.  Sorry, I should have specified that.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima: Shouldn't it be $C_2 = C_1 + \pi/2$ since $\sin 4(\pi/2) = \sin 2\pi = 0$, and $\frac{\pi/2}{2} + C_1 = -\frac{\pi/2}{2} + C_2$

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima: But why? I presume the discontinuity that we're trying to resolve is at the point $x = \pi/2$ because that is where you split the two cases for $\sin 2x$ being positive or negative. If we want a continuous function, then we need $f_1(\pi/2) = f_2(\pi/2)$. When I plug in $x=\pi/2$ into both functions, I obtain $\frac{\pi}{4} + C_1 = -\frac{\pi}{4} + C_2$.

Comment: @WB-man Oh yes of course. sorry. Thanks man.

Comment: I realize that this is a piecewise function, but I do not want that because the physical system that I am trying to represent does not make sense using a piecewise function.  I know mathematically that the function presented is an anti-derivative of the function I presented, but I am asking to find an anti-derivative that is continuous (since there are multiple functions that are anti-derivatives of the function given), and thus helps represent my real physical situation.

Comment: @Josh In physics, there could be discontinuities like in shock waves.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima "Continuous" is not the point. It needs to be differentiable, in fact continuously differentiable.

Comment: @Josh You should remember that $|\sin 2x|$  is a piecewise defined function. (Why does everyone say "piecewise function" when it should be "piecewise defined function?")

Answer (score 0):

If you want an antiderivative for a piecewise defined function, which is what your integrand is, then you shouldn't complain too much when the antiderivative is piecewise defined. There's no way around it: Define

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{x}{2} -\dfrac{\sin (4x)}{8}, & 0\le x \le \frac{\pi}{2}\\ \dfrac{\pi}{2}-\dfrac{x}{2}  +\dfrac{\sin (4x)}{8},& \pi/2\le x \le \pi \end{cases} $$

Then $f$ is the unique antiderviative of $|\sin 2x|\sin 2x$ on $[0,\pi]$ with $f(0)=0.$ Now extend $f$ to all of $\mathbb R$ by making $f$ $\pi$-periodic. Then check that $f(x) + C$ is the general antiderivative of $|\sin 2x|\sin 2x$ on $\mathbb R.$

Comment: I realize that my original function is a piecewise function.  It's not a complaint when I state that I need one function that is good for all of $x$ in my period range, and yet have not seen one.  For example if you integrate the absolute value of $x$ you get a piecewise function, but it is good for all of $x$ and is continuous.  Having two functions does not help me whatsoever which is why I was asking for one function.  There are other things I need to do with this function before I then use it in a program that will be run in parallel.  Trust me, I need only one defined function.

Comment: Yes, but $|x|$ is not periodic. Since I just gave you the general form of an antiderivative in the present case, I can't see what's bothering you.

Comment: Furthermore, since there could be many anti-derivatives of any function, can we find an anti-derivative that is only one continuous function that is good for all of $x$ through the period.

Comment: Yes, I just gave you one. I'm not sure what you mean by "there could be many anti-derivatives of any function" as any two differ by a constant.

Comment: http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/

Comment: @Josh I'm not sure why you posted that link.